# Passing control as in argument WF4

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Im trying to pass a complex object, a `ScriptControl`, as an In argument for workflow. The error I get is:

```
`The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree:
'Literal<ScriptControl>': Literal only supports value types and the immutable type     System.String.  The type ScriptDisplay.ScriptControlcannot be used as a literal.`
```

I am newer to workflow and I understand the problem, but how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code I can't be certain but this is usually caused by using WorkflowInvoker.
e.g.

```
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(workflow,ScriptControl)
```

The way round this is to put the complex object into a dictionary.

```
ScriptControl scriptControl= new ScriptControl{ initialise your object here };

Dictionary<string, object> inputDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "ScriptControl", scriptControl } };

var output = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(workflow, inputDictionary );
```

You then use the dictionary as usual to access the scriptControl object.

e.g.

```
var x = dictionary["ScriptControl"].some property of your ScriptControl object
```

[Ron Jacobs talks more about this here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/26/passing-arguments-to-workflow-activities-again.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Richard. I am looking into this. I can provide some code but I have found with workflow its kind of hard to provide snippets.

Comment: You could post a snippet of how your setting up the WorkflowApplication or WorkflowInvoker objects and passing the ScriptControl into it.

On the XAML side, post an image of the root-level activities arguments.